# Error connecting to raspberrypi using python socket

Tags: python, sockets, networking, raspberry-pi

I am trying to connect to my raspberry pi over the network.
I'm running python as the server on the raspi.
Here is the simple server code I got off the web:

```
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 80
print (host)
print (port)
serversocket.bind((host, port))

serversocket.listen(5)
print ('server started and listening')
while 1:
    (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
    print ("connection found!")
    data = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print (data)
    clientsocket.send("data is sent".encode())
```

Test client code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = "192.168.1.247"
port = 80
s.connect((host,port))
s.send('randomData'.encode())
data = ''
data = s.recv(1024).decode()
print (data)
s.close
```

I have tested it on other computers and these work fine.
When raspi is the CLIENT and the other computer is the server it works fine.  But,
when raspi is SERVER and the other computer is the client, I always get the same error:
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Trying to connect using c#:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.1.247", 80)
```

throws error: `"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"`

Note:
-raspi as client to raspi as server works fine.
-I have done some research and it seems that the most common causes of this is a firewall or bad router.
--I don't think its the router cause I can do a raspy to other computer just fine.
--I'm using the Raspbian “wheezy” Debian distro and I don't think that comes with a firewall.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Is the port open? Also, many Linux distros do include a firewall by default, `iptables`.

Comment: Have you tried using a non-reserved port number, i.e. one above 1024?

Comment: frb, how do i open the port, ill check out the iptables.

Joachim, yes while testing i used 12340 through 12349

Comment: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/routerindex.htm

Comment: frb, all the computers are on my home network so i don't think i need to forward. Plus as i said before, i can connect when raspi is the client and my other computer is the server.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that binding on the result of `gethostname` will always bind to an address that is accessible outside of the local machine ? What happens when you simply bind to '192.168.1.247' or even '' ?

Comment: mmgp: from http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html- "A couple things to notice: we used socket.gethostname() so that the socket would be visible to the outside world. If we had used s.bind(('', 80)) or s.bind(('localhost', 80)) or s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 80)) we would still have a “server” socket, but one that was only visible within the same machine."   So i assume gethostname() would always work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using `socket.gethostname()` which will return the hostname and not the ip. Most probably this means that your socket will bind to that hostname but not the IP, this means that python will only listen to connections to the `hostname` which probably is: raspberrypi

Most probably your machines does not know about that hostname, so you want to use this instead:

```
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

Which it also says in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html)

The thing to remember is that hostname and IP is not the same thing.
However you could bind your hostname to the IP that you have in the /etc/hosts file like this:

`192.168.1.247 raspberrypi`

Comment: hmmm, very interesting.  when i do host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), host = 127.0.1.1.  I guess this means when i do socket.gethostname() it returns an internal ip.  im not sure how to procede...

Comment: ANSWER:  yay fixed it. Simply: host = '192.168.1.247'